# iframe not loading video

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

This is the code I have and it looks right to me. However it's not loading the linked video as it should.

```
var clickHandler3 = function()
{
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe"); 
  iframe.setAttribute("src","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXnJqYwebF8autoplay=1");
  iframe.setAttribute("allow","autoplay"); 
  iframe.style.width = "300px";
  iframe.style.height = "250px";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};

window.addEventListener("load", setup);
```

Comment: does setup call clickHandler3?

Comment: What does setup do?

Comment: I have no idea what setup does. I'm shooting in the dark with this project. This is a knock knock joke HTML webpage that ends with a button that says "Youtube it!" and opens a video related to the knock knock joke.

Comment: you have to upload the full code and explain what you'd try so far. If you are shooting in the dark, you cant expect the community to help you.

Comment: What **exactly** does not work with the given code? Is there any error message?

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you write

> I have no idea what setup does. I'm shooting in the dark with this project. This is a knock knock joke HTML webpage that ends with a button that says "Youtube it!" and opens a video related to the knock knock joke.

I suggest a quick solution for this problem by adding a button that calls `clickHandler3()` with `onclick="clickHandler3()"`

I have changed the iframe to the embed data that is present on youtube for simplicity.

Does this work for you?

```js
function clickHandler3() {
  document.body.innerHTML = '<iframe width="300" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mXnJqYwebF8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
};
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="clickHandler3()">
    click this
  </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickHandler3 =function()

{

  var iFrameElem = document.createElement("iframe");

  iFrameElem.setAttribute('height', '315');

  iFrameElem.setAttribute('width', '560');

  iFrameElem.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/mXnJqYwebF8autoplay=1&mute=1');

  iFrameElem.classList.add('player');

  bodyElem = document.querySelector('body');

  bodyElem.innerHTML = '';

  bodyElem.classList.add('center');

  bodyElem.appendChild(iFrameElem);

};

window.addEventListener("load", setup);
```

Comment: Does this work for you? Where is `bodyElem` defined? does your method `setup()` call `clickHandler3()`?